# Convert to lowercase, uppercase, and then split the string into its own lines

Tags: javascript, split, uppercase, lowercase

I am trying to get a better hang of doing this and have been playing around with strings. What I am trying to do is collect a user input as a string and manipulate it so that when I display the text, whatever they wrote would be first displayed in all lower case, then all uppercase, then all of the text divided into its own line.

So, the output would be like this if I enter: This is an example

this is an example

THIS IS AN EXAMPLE

This

is

an

example

I feel like this is supposed to be a lot easier than it looks, but I am trying to do an all lowercase so far, but cannot get that to work so far (as well as the other two parts). I think that if I get the lowercase right, I just repeat the same thing for uppercase and splitting it.

```
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="test"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var person = prompt("Please enter a phrase");
    if (person != null) {
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML =
        test.toLowerCase;
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML =
        test.toUpperCase;
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML =
        test.split("\n");
    }
}
</script>
```

The above is what I am playing with so far, I get undefined when I click the button to test it. Can someone help me edit this?

Comment: toLowerCase etc are functions .... so you need `()` - also, they return a new string, so you need to say `something = x.toLowerCase()` (oh, you did, you split the line for no reason at all to make the code less readable) also, you have three assignments to the same thing - only the last will be shown - and lastly, `test` will be the `p` element with that ID ... so, not a string so has no toLowerCase etc method

Comment: If you split on `\n`, you won't get spaces converted to `\n` ... I think you need to learn some javascript basics

Comment: Do note that unless you're deliberately inserting HTML markup, it's generally better and safer to assign to `.textContent` instead.

Answer (score 3):

1. functions are invoked using `()`
2. your variable is `person` not `test`
3. you want to split on `space` not `\n`
4. you want to ADD to test innerHTML, not replace it each time
5. to get line breaks in HTML, use `<br>` tag

I've gone for code that assigns innerHTML once, as this is more performant than adding to it a bit at a time - of course, with such a simple example there's no perceived difference, however I thought I should mention why I chose to use this odd methodology

```js
function myFunction() {
    var person = prompt("Please enter a phrase");
    if (person != null) {
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = [
          person.toLowerCase(),
          person.toUpperCase(),
          person.split(" ").join('<br>')
        ].join("<br>");
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="test"></p>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much, I understand my errors!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to split the string into words first and use join() function with `<br />` tags to render them into multiple lines of words.

```
function myFunction() {
    var person = prompt("Please enter a phrase");
        if (person != null) {
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML +=
        person.toLowerCase() + "<br />";
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML +=
        person.toUpperCase() + "<br />";
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML +=
        person.split(' ').join('<br />');
    }
}
```